# How to retrieve exact matching records using SOQL?

Tags: soql

Let's say there are 5 accounts in the system as below:

1. Account1
2. ACCOUNT1
3. account1
4. ACCount1
5. acCOUNT1

**I want the SOQL query to return me only 1 record: account1**

So i tried the below query:

```
Select Id, Name from Account where name = 'account1'
```

But this returns me all the 5 records. How can I overcome this?

Comment: You can check my solution which should work for you.

Answer (score 4):

SOQL is [almost always case-insensitive](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm):

> String comparisons using the equals operator are case-sensitive for unique case-sensitive fields and case-insensitive for all other fields.

Account Name is not a field that meets these conditions (unique case-sensitive), which are part of the definition of a field. That combination of attributes is often seen on a custom External Id field, although it can occur elsewhere as well.

Most parts of Salesforce are, in fact, case-insensitive. To compare strings for case-sensitive equality, you must use the `String.equals()` method. Note that the Apex `==` operator is also case-insensitive.

You would need to perform the query and then iterate over the results in Apex to make case-sensitive comparisons in order to locate the exact, case-sensitive match.

Comment: You just beat me to it :)

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on "Account Name is not a unique case-sensitive field, which would be an External ID."? You can actually mark non-unique fields to be external id's and a field which is unique is not necessarily marked as an external id.

Comment: @rael_kid You're right, I oversimplified. Let me revise that.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can not achieve it using the simple SOQL query only as SOQL is case-insensitive. You will have to use the Map collection for finding the records. In the Map collection you can have the name as the key as Map keys are case-sensitive.

```
Map<String, Account> mapAccounts = Map<String, Account>();
for( Account acc : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Account1' ]){
   mapAccounts.put( acc.Name, acc );
}

mapAccounts.get('Account1') //will give you the account if it's there
```

Comment: This does not achieve the poster's objective of a case-sensitive match. It returns one account per case-insensitive Account name, and which is selected is essentially undefined.

Comment: @DavidReed I think I got it wrong. You are right. I will update my answer.

Comment: I think you have a useful answer here. May I suggest explicitly pointing out *why* this works (String Map keys are case-sensitive) to make it more useful? I'd be happy to upvote.

Comment: @DavidReed - Now, I hope it makes some sense.

Comment: Yes, much improved and an important note about how collections work! +1.

Answer (score 0):

From the Force.com SOQL and SOSL Reference on WHERE conditionExpression:

```
comparisonOperator Case-insensitive operators that compare values.

Operator =
Name Equals
Description Expression is true if the value in the specified fieldName equals the specified value in the expression. String comparisons using the equals operator are case-sensitive for unique case-sensitive fields and case-insensitive for all other fields.
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, string comparison is case-insensitive

Check the documentation for further details [SFDC ConditionExpression](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_sosl_where.htm)